# Useradd and su strange terminal behavior

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I used useradd to create a user called oracle

After that I used su oracle i get in terminal just a $

Do you know why the terminal is not something like oracle@laptophp:~$  and is just a $ ?

Comment: Curious. What distribution are you running on?

Comment: i use ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably did not create your new user with `useradd -m`. The `-m` copies the default ("skeleton") shell profile files from /etc to new users home dir.

To resolve the issue, recreate the account or just copy the `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` and `.profile` files from some other user account or from `/etc/profile/`.

Answer (score 2):

You might also take a look at [PS1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/) environment variable. If you type `export PS1="$ "`, your prompt will be just a dollar sign.

Answer (score 1):

I have been having the exact same problem. Turns out there is an alternative to "useradd" called "adduser". This automatically copies the skeleton and everything needed.

```
adduser <username>
```

This code prompts you to fill in information about the user, and copies everything needed (as well as setting up a user directory).

Answer (score 0):

After running the `env` command under my new user I noticed that:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
```

If you run the `useradd` command with `useradd -ms /bin/bash [USERNAME]` then it should work as expected.

**`-s`** allows you to modify the default shell.